# Laravel. Job Class not found on server (linux)

Tags: linux, laravel, ubuntu, queue, jobs

There is some problem with Laravel and server:

I created a job and tested it in localhost and it worked fine.

Then, I transfer it on the server and got an error:

> Class "App/Jobs/JobName" not found.

I suppose it because of some server settings. Because I didn't have the same problems on localhost or in another projects (servers).

I didn't find answer in google. Maybe someone can solve this?

Controller:

```
use App\Jobs\PushNotification; 
/* some logic */
$this->dispatch(new PushNotification($alarm,$receivers));
```

Job:

```
namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Models\User;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;

class PushNotification implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

/* some logic */
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe it will help:

1. Execute the command `composer dump-autoload` in your local machine's terminal.
2. Re-upload to server files that you have problem with.
3. Make sure that naming is correct. You wrote error: `Class "App/Jobs/JobName" not found.`, and tour class name is  `PushNotification`, I am not sure if it was your aim.
4. Make on server `composer dump-autoload` (i hope you make also `composer update` on server - to get the all dependencies)

Good luck!

Comment: what about: Make sure that naming is correct. You wrote error: Class "App/Jobs/JobName" not found., and tour class name is  PushNotification, I am not sure if it was your aim.?

Comment: its ok. JobName = PushNotification. I use phpStorm and it "see" this class. Localhost (windows) see it too. But not server

Comment: Make on server `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: (i hope you make also composer update on server - to get the all dependencies)

Comment: yep! composer dump-autoload on server make the new error (i hope old error is solved). Thank you!